# Value always return null

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, screenshot

First off, I'll explain my program.

I have one winform that I use as my control panel. From here I have the ability to take a screen shot of my desktop using the mouse to define the area. Much like how the snipping tool works within windows.

The screen shot is generated using my screen shot class which is ran by another form called Form1. This second form has no other code in it but is simply used to generate the rectangle the screen shot will use. From here, the taken screen shot is stored in the clip board and passed back to my Screenshot class.

Now, from here what I want is a picture box in my control panel to display this taken image. Exactly like how the snipping tool works. However, the code I have wrote to pass this image to the control panel from the screen shot class complains that the event handler is always returning as null.

The code I have wrote for this is as follows:

```
 Image img = (Image)bitmap;
 if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

 ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
 OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
```

I've tried commenting out the if statement but then the processing OnUpdateStatus throws an exception saying it no longer exists.

Now, in my control panel form I am trying to grab that image and display with the following code:

```
    private ScreenCapture _screenCap;

    public ControlPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
        _screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;

    }



    private void _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {

        imagePreview.Image = e.CapturedImage;
    }
```

I've spent hours on this but i cannot work out why the image won't display in the image box on my ControlPanel. Can anyone with a fresh set of eyes help me out? Why is it the screen shot image I take, isn't being displayed in my picture box held on my ControlPanel?

Comment: be specific and post the relevant code only.

Comment: `I've spent hours on this` We don't want to spend hours on this, pls post relevant or suspected code only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem, I think (there's a lot of code to skim through - a short but complete example would have been better):

```
ScreenCapture capture = new ScreenCapture();
capture.CaptureImage(...);
```

That's a *new instance* of `ScreenCapture`. It doesn't have any event handlers attached to it (which is why you're seeing a value of `null` for `OnUpdateStatus`. If you want to use the instance that you've created in the `ControlPanel` class, you'll want to pass that to your `Form1` (e.g. in the constructor).

Comment: Even though I'm storing the image in the clipboard? I'm sorry, but i've no idea how to do what your suggesting.

Comment: @N0xus: Storage of the image is irrelevant. You're looking at the value of `OnUpdateStatus` within the `CaptureImage` method, right? So it *matters* which instead of `ScreenCapture` you call the method on. I suspect you need to pass `_screenCap` to the constructor of `Form1` (which would need to store it in a field) so that you could use the *same instance* when you call `CaptureImage` within `Form1`.